# SQLite not finding field in trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I have two tables. One is deductions and the other deductTrans. idDeductions is the key field in Deductions, and it is a foreign key in deductTrans. I've got a couple of things I want to automatically do in deductions when a deductTrans is inserted. I have this trigger, which compiles.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trig_DeductTrans AFTER INSERT ON DeductTrans
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Deductions
    SET remainingCt = remainingCT - 1
    WHERE
        idDeductions = New.idDeductions ;
    END;
```

When I insert a record, I receive the following error: "No such column as idDeductions"

I'm at a loss. I've tried changing the WHERE to Deductions.idDeductions = New.idDeductions but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Show the definition of both tables.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite claims that the `Deductions` table has no column named 'idDeductions'.  You haven't given us any means to check, but most likely it's right.  I observe that your trigger is on a different table (`DeductTrans`), which apparently you expect also to have a column `idDeductions`.

Most likely the corresponding column in `Deductions` is named differently.  For example, perhaps it is named simply `id`.

Comment: I wish it were. It would explain a lot, but here's the first part of the Create code: CREATE TABLE "Deductions" (
"idDeductions"  TEXT NOT NULL,....

Comment: So, could it be `DeductTrans` that has the differently-named column?  Or as a wild guess, is it possible that you are not inserting an explicit value for `DeductTrans.idDeductions` when this trigger fails?  (I'm doubtful it *should* fail if you don't, but software has bugs.)

Answer (score 0):

OK. Bizarre. I was testing this on Navicat Premium. Saved the trigger in disgust, closed the program, and went to lunch. Came back and thought I'd try it again. Worked like a charm. Beats the heck our of me!